# Ge count on all tables based on Date ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I am trying to get count for all tables based on a column `APPL_REC_LAST_UPD_DT`

Working query that returns all count for all tables

```
select owner, table_name, nvl(num_rows,-1)
from SYS.all_tables
WHERE owner LIKE '%noob%'
order by nvl(num_rows,-1) desc;
```

With the above query I would like to know if possible how to query the count based on a date or everything before that date.

Use Case:

I want to get the count of everything that happened on or before a certain date.  For example count for anything before 12-20-2023.

thank you.

Comment: You cannot use sys.all_tables to get the number of rows in a table that have a certain date range for a column of the table. You can query a table directly and count how many rows are in it that meet some date condition on a column.

Answer (score 0):

Short of trying to approximate using statistics histograms (not reliable or simple), you will need to query the tables themselves to get a count by date column value. If there are lots of tables with this column and you need to do them all, you can script it easily enough:

```
CREATE TABLE count_results (owner varchar2(128), table_name varchar2(128), datecol date, cnt integer);
/
BEGIN
  FOR rec_table IN (SELECT *
                      FROM all_tab_columns
                     WHERE owner LIKE '%NOOB%'
                       AND column_name = 'APPL_REC_LAST_UPD_DT')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO count_results 
                       SELECT :owner, 
                              :tablename, 
                              TRUNC('||rec_table.column_name||'), 
                              COUNT(*) 
                         FROM "'||rec_table.owner||'"."'||rec_table.table_name||'" 
                     GROUP BY TRUNC('||rec_table.column_name||')' 
            USING IN rec_table.owner, rec_table.table_name;

    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
SELECT owner,table_name,SUM(cnt) prior_count
  FROM count_results
 WHERE datecol < TO_DATE('2023-12-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY owner,table_name
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, how would this differ if I wanted a count of everything before 2023-12-20?

Comment: @NoobCoder Add a `WHERE` clause to the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement to apply that filter.

Comment: @NoobCoder, I edited the final query in my answer. You can filter either in the insert-select or in the final query of the output table, which gives you more flexibility to change your mind about the date desired.